# How to replace 2 subsequent characters with single character

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a requirement to replace subsequent(2) single quotes(') with one single quote(') using regular expression in javascript.

For example if the target string is "**''''**", Then after the replacement the resulting string should be "**''**" converting 4 single quotes in to 2 single quotes (matching 2 pairs and replacing them with 2 single quotes)

Comment: You have not yet accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by doing replace `str.replace(/'{2}/g, "'");`

Comment: @JanarthananChandrasekaran you can accept answer now

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
var r = "''''".replace(/''/g, "'");
//=> "''"
```